# Problems with MVC getting models for my Views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Maybe this is a silly problem with a very simple solution but still is a problem for me.The thing is that when I'm going to create a new strongly typed View for the action "Index" in my controller "UserController" Visual Studio is not detecting the model "User" I want to provide to my View in the observer.I'm using SharpLite template in my project so I'm storing my models(In this case "User") in "MyProject.Domain" library.If anyone knows how to fix this, please help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the Model class, `User`, is publicly accessible and the directive in the View is `fully qualified`:

**View Markup:**

```
@model Some.Namespace.User
```

Comment: As I said before, it was a silly question after all ,I forgot to put my entity public,So thanks a lot

Comment: Figured that's what it was (as the default new class re-factoring in visual studio sets the accessibility to private) ... Accept the answer if it helped...

Comment: Sorry but I'm new to Stack Overflow and my current reputation doesn't alloud me to increment you points,so is a double thanks...:)

Answer (score 0):

You have to compile the solution after adding the model before your model is visible in the VS add view dialog. And your class must be public visible as mentioned from Xander.